# How to get all dependencies (modules) used?

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules

I try to get all the dependencies my project uses.

I looked at the `go.mod` file, though this only contains dependencies/modules that I added, and not the dependencies from my dependencies.

Looking at the `go.sum` file, this looked more promising, though then I noticed it contains multiple duplicates. Even though I only use one version of the dependency. As an example:

```
github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.0/go.mod h1:FsONVRAS9T7sI+LIUmWTfcYkHO4aIWwzhcaSAoJOfIk=
github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2 h1:ROPKBNFfQgOUMifHyP+KYbvpjbdoFNs+aK7DXlji0Tw=
github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2/go.mod h1:XVQd3VNwM+JqD3oG2Ue2ip4fOMUkwXdXDdiuN0vRsmY=
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1/go.mod h1:9q0QmTI4eRPtz6boOQmLYwt+qCgq0jsYwAQnmE0givc=
```

How can I get a list containing only all actively used dependencies/modules?

Comment: Maybe check out https://github.com/kisielk/godepgraph

Comment: You may use one fixed version of a package, but your imports have their own `go.mod` files which may use different versions of that same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about these 2 files, and technically you can clean up the go.sum by adding replace statements to the go.mod file. Though, it is not reliable that you (and your team) will always keep this clean.

In my opinion, the best way to get the list you are looking for is `go list -m all` (or `go list --json -m all` to get a json response). It will list you all the dependencies recursively in your project. But filters out the unused ones.